# How do I delay USB startup on boot?

Tags: usb

I am using Zoneminder with a USB web-cam and also analogue inputs from a PCI capture card. Sometimes when the server boots, USB is detected first (and assigned `/dev/video0`) and at other times the capture card is detected first (and assigned `/dev/video0` - `/dev/video3` as its a 4 channel card) and USB is assigned `/dev/video4`.
I am after some way to force the system to only detect USB and the Capture Card in a certain order so the assignments don't change between boots.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to force detection order and thus stabilize device node numbers this way. As @Someone_Out_There mentioned, the expected way to approach this problem is to use udev rules to set up consistent aliases for these devices (e.g. based on their USB IDs) and rely on those aliases.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking into using udev rules.  You can create symlinks to the underlying device so no matter which order they are detected you use the alias name that never changes.  See ["Writing udev rules" by Daniel Drake (dsd)](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).

Comment: Hello Someone_Out_There! Welcome to AskUbuntu. I'm afraid I downvoted your answer, because it lacks any detail. Why don't you extract the useful information from the page you linked to, and include the link for reference?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This does not answer the question.